# After installing Ubuntu, I cannot use my mouse or keyboard on a Windows7 boot up

Tags: boot, dual-boot, keyboard, windows-7, mouse

I am a complete noob and somehow managed to install Ubuntu.
What I remember from the process:

1. After making the bootable USB and getting to the install process of Ubuntu I made some partitions on my second 1TB storage decide (DRIVE D). Now some context, my windows7 is installed on the first storage device, it's a SSD(DRIVE C), I don think I touched it. So I made a 100gb partition on my D drive within windows before even installing Ubuntu, but when in the installaian I had to divide that up into three again; "/"(50gb), "/home"(34gb) and swap space(16gb).
2. I know that I accidentally first touched the 900gb space of my drive D that was being used by my windows for storage and almost partitioned it, the actual windows was on C. But I clicked the option revert and it shouldn't have damaged anything.. Regardless, I think most of my drivers (also mouse/keyboardd) would be on my C drive.
3. First time didn't work because I chose my root to be in the same drive as Windows, and it didn't like that or something, so did the installation again and now chose the root to be in the D drive. I had to choose D drive to startup, and woohoo; Ubuntu!
4. After messing around with Ubuntu and failing to do what I initially installed it for (that's a whole other story), oh and on which I btw could acces the whole of D drive, also my windows storage. I rebooted and tried to login on my Windows, my mouse wouldn't move and typing on my keyboard results is less than nothing.

Is it my drivers I dungoof'd? What can I do.

TL;DR: Maybe have messed up during Ubuntu installation, mouse&keyboard don't work on Windows7 startup now.

Thank you so much if you already have taken the time to read this wall of text.

Greetings from The Netherlands!

Answer (score 0):

Okay bollocks. I just went into BIOS and forced it to do the USB compatibility patch. It works. So whoever is experiencing the same, try to find the option to ENABLE the USB compatibility patch.